# Is it possible to increase the stack size in CEF/CefSharp?

Tags: c#, html, stack, mp3, cefsharp

I'm using cef.redist.x86.3.3497.1840 with with CefSharp in a C# project.  I have a set of HTML pages that play mp3 audio and they work fine in Chrome, but when I try to load them with CEF/CefSharp, the visuals are OK, but CEF/CefSharp gives me the message

`"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`.

This happens before I even attempt to play the audio (which BTW will NOT play in this context), even though I can load individual .mp3 files and play them with the HTML5 gizmo provided by CEF.

I've never had a hint of a problem using these pages with Chrome.

What's going on with the CEF/CefSharp stack?

Can I somehow tell it to use a larger stack?

Do I need to rebuild it myself with a larger stack?

Both 64-bit Release and Debug builds of CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms yield the same stack overflow message.

Comment: That exception usually happens if there is a infinite recursion, propably due to a bug. If it is that, increasing the stacksize would only change how long it takes to get there. It had to be set very low to cause an issue in normal opeartions (20 or less).

Comment: Does it reproduce with a 64bit build? You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing

Comment: @Christopher: If it were infinite recursion, wouldn't that happen in Chrome as  well?   Or maybe you were referring to a bug in CEF, not my JS?

Comment: @M.Robinson: Each Browser has diffrent code to handle each and every format. Each Browser handles slightly damage/incorrect formats differntly. Just because it puts some part of CEF/CefSharp into ifinite recursion, does not mean it does the same to Chrome. That is why we use different browsers to test stuff. And why we have to use different browsers to test stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I did reproduced with both x86 and x64 builds with the following websites:

https://pass.carrefour.es/zona-cliente

https://online.bankofcyprus.com/netteller-web/

with a C++ CEF-based project. (I think it was CEF branch 3282 - Chrome v60 - at that time).

If I remember correctly, this also reproduced with cefclient.

The issue was indeed triggered by very large javascript code ending up into the page.

What I did was to increase stack size in .vcxproj:

```
<StackReserveSize>0x00120000</StackReserveSize>
```

(so add 128 KB extra to the default 1 MB).

NodeJS has a --v8-option called --stack_size that sounds similar, but I don't know if there something similar in CEF (at least I don't recall to be directly exposed).

What I commented on the fix at that time was:

```
Increase stack size from the default 1MB adding 128 KB more. 
This seems to be necessary for renderer's V8, which is trashing 
the page guard instead of raising JS RangeError or stack overflow, 
but blows up with STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION or STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW *and* 
overwriting the first frame. 

The debugger itself is defeated since there is no context to determine which 
10000+ lines JS blows up the parser.
```

I'm not exactly sure why V8 behaves in this way (I could be entirely wrong, since it was a critical fix for multiple support issues and I simply used more a trial-and-error approach rather than thorough debugging).

For convenience, here are the reported bugs (edited):

```
[*edited*] webpage crashes if you access https://pass.carrefour.es/zona-cliente
We have internal repro 100%.
```

and

```
If you access the webpage https://online.bankofcyprus.com/netteller-web/ in [*edited*], the tab crashes unexpectedly:

"The webpage has quit unexpectedly. The problem may have been caused by an exception, or another exceptional condition such as blocking scripts or requests generated by the webpage.
Please Reload page or go Back to the previous page."
We have internal repro. Full dump can be found here: *edited*
```

Issues that might be related:
V8

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8234

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8053

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6617

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6438

Chromium:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753705